# attach file in mail instead of download in browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am generating a file in my (web)project in browser for download, but when project is opened in tablet/mobile(iOS/android/Blackberry), i want to attach that file as e-mail attachment instead of download on device.
I am using JavaScript can anyone suggest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send an email directly from JavaScript without help from a server.  You should look into these options:

1. Setup your own mail server, and have your javascript notify your server when you want to send mail.
2. http://mailchimp.com/
3. http://sendgrid.com/